# How to enable output Window in VS2013?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, output-window

I am using VS2013 very first time and some how I can't find Output Window where I can see messages being printed by using `Debug.WriteLine` or `Console.WriteLine`

How do I enable this? All I see Window of CallStack

Comment: Ctrl +W, O should bring it up. If you still can't see it you may need to resize it, it should be at the bottom of your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the main menu:

DEBUG > Windows > Output

It may have been added to a window with multiple tabs

[image]

Alternately you could try resetting all visual studio settings.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms247075%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

CTRL+W,O will do or you can set it by `TOOLS`->option-> project and solutions->click the check box  Show Output window when build option

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+W,O and output window will open. If not check in the bottom of IDE and expand it. Thanks